# What exactly is happening when we use the same word twice in a row?

Tags: meaning

Example:

> A: Hey, I just bought a mouse.
>   B: A mouse mouse? Or a computer mouse?

What is this exactly?
And are there any rules?

Comment: The first "mouse" of the pair is being used as an adjective.  In terms of syntax it's no different from "red mouse".

Comment: Had I been B:  A: Hey, I just bought a mouse. B:Did you get a cage too, with the little Ferris wheel that he can run around in?  A:No, I mean a computer mouse!  B:So the Ferris wheel is simulated on the screen??

Comment: @HotLicks: Groan! But +1 anyway. Don

Comment: The phenomenon is called red duplication. Some languages use it with verbs to indicate completed action (Swahili). I think of it as intensification.

Comment: [Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

Answer (score 19):

This is a kind of *retronym*. It has been called [contrastive focus reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication).

Comment: Retronym: a better term by virtue of its parsimoniousness! You deserve to have the #1 answer. I bow to you, saying "I am not worthy. I am not worthy" (seriously--well, kinda). Cheers and kudos. Don

Answer (score 9):

Rhetorically, there is, by implication, a combination of synecdoche and metonymy involved in the "mouse mouse" locution.

These two figures of speech involve part-to-whole relationships and/or the substitution of parts-to-whole relationships.

> All hands on deck [implied is "the deck of the *ship*"]

is metonymic because the word *hands* is a substitute for the word *sailors*. Yes, hands are part and parcel of sailors' bodies, but those hands are also, synecdochally, parts of a whole.

"Mouse mouse," then, means in essence "a real mouse" (or perhaps more accurately, a "live mouse" or a "flesh and blood mouse"). Just as a computer mouse imitates a real mouse by being small, having a "tail" (if it's a wired mouse, that is), and moving around the mouse pad in little and quick movements, so also does the real mouse by virtue of being small, having a tail, and moving about in little and quick movements, correspond synecdochally to the faux (computer) mouse.

This inter-correspondence or analogical similarity of features is at the heart of the way the synecdoche/metonymy figure is employed in the "mouse mouse" locution.

Comment: +1 for "a real mouse." (cf the twisted, imo, souls who came up with and purchase "**[The real mouse, mouse](http://gizmodo.com/255928/the-real-mouse-mouse)**"!)

Comment: +1 Having read through the possible duplicates and their answers, this answer is the *only* one to spell out that when the word is repeated, replacing the first one with "real" gives the intended meaning.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK i like your sentiment. i would offer that this construction denotes the original or most common meaning of the word, rather than some newer meaning.

Comment: @AndyT, It is not clear to me that 'real' achieves any clarity at all. My computer mouse is perfectly real--I have it right here. Surely  'biological mouse' would resolve the matter.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I agree with you. A "flesh-and-blood mouse" would be a wordier, though more accurate, expression. I've edited my original answer.  Don

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I never said replacing the duplication with "real" gave clarity, I said that the duplication *means* "real". I could envisage a situation where someone says "You mean a flash-and-blood mouse" and the response is "No, a *mouse* mouse", meaning a computer mouse, because to them that's what a "real" mouse is.

Answer (score 2):

This is an instance of 'noun as adjective'. The usage is explained in the article quoted below in some detail.

The important point is that there is no difference in *grammar* between 'mouse mouse' and 'computer mouse'.  In both cases a noun is used to qualify another noun. You can think of it as a coincidence that the first phrase uses the same word twice.

The reason for this usage is that computer mice are more commonly found in most houses now than are real mice. That represents a big change in our language--before personal computers, the reverse was true.

That said, there is an element of humour involved and the repetition sounds 'cute'. It would have been clearer to say,  "A house mouse or a computer mouse?".

**Comment**

There is unlikely to be a phrase covering this specific use of a repeated word (in my opinion) because the phenomenon that gave rise to it is very rare or even unique. Maybe someone will prove me wrong with other examples.

---

> **Noun as Adjective**
>   Sometimes we use a noun to describe another noun. In that case, the
>   first noun "acts as" an adjective... The "noun as adjective" always
>   comes first...
>
> [English Club Website](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm)